# A conjunction that implies "associated with" or "belonging to"?

Tags: conjunctions

I used "of which" to connect two sentences as follows:

> I study master of architecture in Aalto University of which all my courses except the master thesis have been completed.

The sequence of information is important, since I am introducing myself. But I am not sure if I should use "in which", "of which", or another approach to connect these sentences.

Comment: You don't study "master of architecture". Either you study *the* or *a* master of architecture (in which "master" would be a person). If "master of architecture" is a degree programme, then you study *for* a master's degree *in* Architecture, but it'd be easier to say that you're a Master's student in architecture... In any case, "of which" doesn't really work. I would rewrite the sentence completely (e.g. "... and have completed all necessary courses. I'm currently writing my thesis on ABC under supervision of Prof. X."). Also, you don't study *in* Aalto University, but *at* Aalto University.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rewrite. *The Chicago Manual of Style* capitalizes *Master* and *Architecture*.

**I am a Master of Architecture student at Aalto University. I have completed all of my coursework, but I am still working on my thesis.**

Or **coursework; however, ...**